# How do I create a Django form that allows for user to enter their own value for "other" radio option

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Model in Django called `VolunteerOpportunity` that has an attribute called `event_name`. I'd like the `event_name` attribute to be a foreign key to another table where the app admins can create default event names such as Career Fair, Senior Bingo, PAWS, etc. I'd also like there to be an "Other" option, that when selected, a user can type in his/her own value. I'd like that value to be stored, however, I don't want it to show up for users as an option the next time the form is loaded.

I've attached an example of what I'd like, but this is done through Google Forms.

[Google Form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZOt6.png)

How should I structure the Model(s) and form to allow for such a structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the bat, I have found [this](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2014/05/implementing-multiple-radio-select.html). Do note that the article is four years old  - but the general principles should still apply:

### Create a custom widget subclassing [MultiWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget)

This widget will combine the radio select widgets with the text input widget for the 'other choice' in the `MultiWidget.widgets` attribute. You must implement the `decompress` method; as the name implies the method is used to turn a single value stored in your db into multiple values that should mesh with the widgets defined in `self.widgets`.
I doubt that the way of rendering the widget properly as described in the linked article still applies in newer django version (for example `forms.RadioSelect.renderer` is not a thing anymore) so you are going to have to do some tinkering yourself.

### Create a custom field subclassing [MultiValueField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield)

Much like the custom widget above, this form field will combine the (Model)ChoiceField and the 'other option' CharField into a single entity. This custom field must implement the `compress` method - complimentary to the widget's `decompress` method. The value returned by `compress` is used for validation, cleaning and saving.

### Make a custom form that uses the custom field in place of the default formfield

(self-explanatory)

### Configure the model's field choices or dynamically assign choices to the form

If your list of default choices is **very** static, you can just define it on the model (like in the article). Otherwise you could assign the form field's choices during `form.__init__`. Either way you should append the 'other option' to the list of default choices.

---

If that is too much hassle, you could look into using implementations of select fields that also allow creating new records/choices: [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) or [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light). Or maybe there's already such a field out there, because I doubt you are the first to want that functionality.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnZ. So are you found the suitable package for this purpose?